# Как скачать альбом фотографий (получить данные) c помощью pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Я делаю бота, который собирает некоторую информацию, включая фотографии, и мне нужно сохранять фотографии. Мне удалось сохранить только 1 фотографию из альбома, как сохранить все?

я использую python3 с pyTelegramBotAPI

```py
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, commands=['test'])
def test(message):
   text_message = 'some question' 
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id,text_message) 
   bot.register_next_step_handler(message, test2) 

def test2(message):
   file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[-1].file_id)
   print(file_info)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отправьте альбом и посмотрите `getUpdates` вручную через json viewer. Видно, что альбом из двух фото содержит 2 сообщения, в каждом из которых хранятся по 4 `file_id` для разной степени сжатости.
Таким образом вы обрабатываете первое фото из альбома, но остальные ваш декоратор пропускает.

В реализации вам может помочь проверка следующих сообщений на принадлежность одной `message.media_group_id`